# invoking R plumber code via jquery

Tags: jquery, r, ajax, web-services, plumber

I've created my R file and plumber code. I am able to access it if I paste the url in the browser.

```
http://localhost:8000/calculate_score?date=07%2F03%2F2017
```

but when I try to access it with via jquery ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost:8000/calculate_score?date="+JSON.stringify(encodeURIComponent($( "#datepicker" ).val())),
             type:"POST",
             dataType: "jsonp"
          }).then(function(data) {

                alert("sucess:"+data);


          var obj = JSON.parse(output);

}
```

I get a connection refused error.

```
GET http://<my ip>:8000/calculate_score?date=%2207%2F04%2F2017%22&callback=jQuery1102037260698059372777_1502383033542&_=1502383033543 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How to resolve the issue? I am using chrome. I tried with jsonp and type "GET" as well.

EDIT: Including my plumber.R code

```
r <- plumb("<my_path>/api_functions.R") 
r$run(port=8000)
```

Comment: Can you include your `plumber.R` file? I don't think you want to use `dataType: "jsonp"` and if that URL works directly in your browser then you probably want a `GET` request, not `POST`. Lastly, I'd check that the request formatting of your date selector is what you'd expect.

Comment: @JeffAllen I had tried GET before trying POST and similary "json" before using jsonp. those were some suggestions from other SO answers. but no luck unfortunately. I've included my plumber code.